# Require help in creating JSR223 request for getting csv data & parsing to Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a HTTP request whose body data(which is in Json) is given below

```
{
          "$ct": false,
          "Source": [
            "DFT"
          ],
          "Type": "View",
          "Apply": "Filter",
          "Format": "PDF",
          "validationFactors": {
            "Expand": "attributes",
            "FilterConstraints": [{
                "type": "articles",
                "Apply": "All",
                "CreatedUpdated": [{
                  "title": "UN",
                  "FirstName": "Alia",
                  "MiddleName": "",
                  "LastName": "Stve",
                  "Datatype": "string",
                  "Encode": "Pswd",
                  "Local": "project",
                  "Id": "146FG"
                }]
              },
              {
                "type": "articles",
                "Apply": "All",
                "CreatedUpdated": [{
                  "title": "UA",
                  "FirstName": "ABC",
                  "MiddleName": "XYZ",
                  "LastName": "TFG",
                  "Datatype": "string",
                  "Encode": "title",
                  "Local": "project",
                  "Id": "ST6879GIGOYGO790"
                }]
              }

            ]
          }
        }
```

In above Json,I have paratermize below attributes, these values are stored in csv ."title": "${title}","FirstName": "${FirstName}","MiddleName": "${MiddleName}","LastName": "${LastName}","Datatype": "${Datatype}","Encode": "${Encode}","Local": "${Local}","Id": "${Id}"

Problem : I have created a JSR223 below my http request, but in script area how to get data from csv and parametrize it? Thanks in advance
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You ain't need JSR223 PreProcessor for this, just placing JSON Payload into "Body data" tab of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler should be sufficient, just replace hard-coded values with the [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) from the [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) reference names.

[image: JMeter API JSON Post]

You might also need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and configure it to send [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#MIME_type)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem with this approach is like I will get only one value for (title,first name,middle name, last name, ...ID) but i want multiple values. i am having (title,first name, middle name, last name,... ID) more than 1 times

Comment: This set is repeating hence i have parametrize it                                           
                  "title": "UA",
                  "FirstName": "ABC",
                  "MiddleName": "XYZ",
                  "LastName": "TFG",
                  "Datatype": "string",
                  "Encode": "title",
                  "Local": "project",
                  "Id": "ST6879GIGOYGO790"